# hadoop 2.4.0 streaming generic parser options using TAB as separator

Tags: python, hadoop, utf-8, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I know that the tab is default input separator for fields :

```
stream.map.output.field.separator
stream.reduce.input.field.separator
stream.reduce.output.field.separator
mapreduce.textoutputformat.separator
```

but if i try to write the generic parser option :

```
stream.map.output.field.separator=\t (or)  
stream.map.output.field.separator="\t"
```

to test how hadoop parses white space characters like "\t,\n,\f" when used as separators. I observed that hadoop reads it as \t character but not "" tab space itself. I checked it by printing each line in reducer (python) as it reads using :

```
sys.stdout.write(str(line))
```

My mapper emits key/value pairs as : `key        value1         value2`

using `print (key,value1,value2,sep='\t',end='\n')` command.

So I expected my reducer to read each line as : `key        value1         value2` too, but instead `sys.stdout.write(str(line))` printed :

`key        value1         value2      \\with trailing space`

From [Hadoop streaming - remove trailing tab from reducer output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133290/hadoop-streaming-remove-trailing-tab-from-reducer-output), I understood that the trailing space is due to `mapreduce.textoutputformat.separator` not being set and left as default.

So, this confirmed my assumption that hadoop considered my total map output :

`key        value1         value2`

as key and value as empty Text object since it read the separator from `stream.map.output.field.separator=\t` as "\t" character instead of "" tab space itself.

Please help me understand this behavior and how can I use \t as a separator if I want to.

Answer (score 1):

You might be having this issue **"-D stream.map.output.field.separator=." specifies "." as the field separator for the map outputs, and the prefix up to the fourth "." in a line will be the key and the rest of the line (excluding the fourth ".") will be the value. If a line has less than four "."s, then the whole line will be the key and the value will be an empty Text object (like the one created by new Text("")).** [Here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html#Customizing+How+Lines+are+Split+into+Key%2FValue+Pairs) it is clearly mentioned how the separator is being used, and also how many of such separator occurences needs to be considered, when identifying map key and value. Also there are fields related to partitioning, based on which the reducer will be handled. As you want the separator to be changed, I think, you have to verify this also related to partitioning and reducer.

Comment: I am not giving any field number in my argument and AFAI understood, the  issue you mentioned arises only if I provide a field number and if I give less than my intended field number.  I did not understand the part about "fields related to partitioning". However I was debugging the Hadoop 2.4.0 source code, interestingly, in "PipeMapper.java" : the line `mapOutputFieldSeparator = job.get("stream.map.output.field.separator", "\t").getBytes("UTF-8");` outputs `t` omitting \ character when I give `stream.map.output.field.separator=\t` as argument and `TAB` (white characters) whenwithout argument.

Comment: Try adding the parameter "stream.map.output.field.separator" value of "\t", in you job java code. Not sure why it is having issue picking up from else where

Comment: This is a streaming job. We can only pass mappers/reducers as scripts/executables and I am using python scripts for my mapper and reducer. We cannot access job object here.