# hadoop-streaming.jar adds x'09' at the end of each line

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to merge some *_0 (part files in HDFS) files in a HDFS location using the below hadoop-streaming.jar command.

```
  hadoop jar $HDPHOME/hadoop-streaming.jar -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=1 -input $INDIR -output $OUTTMP/${OUTFILE}  -mapper cat -reducer cat
```

Things work fine - Except that, I get into problems, as, the result from above command seem to add x'09' to the end of each line.

We have Hive tables defined on top of the part files (which are replaced with the merged file) where the last field is defined as BIGINT. Since, the merged file adds the x'09' to the last field - the same definition of the tbale now shows NULL in the last field in Hue (as 510408 is no longer a number as X'09' is added to it).

e.g.

Data in part file.

```
00000320  7c 35 31 30 34 30 38 0a                           ||510408.|
```

Data in merged file (result of above command)

```
00000320  7c 35 31 30 34 30 38 09  0a                       ||510408..|
```

How do I avoid this from happening? Is there some option that I can set in the command to prevent this?

Appreciate your time for any help/pointers.

Comment: `x09` is the TAB special char. What is the default field separator for Hadoop Streaming?

Comment: Did you consider creating a Hadoop archive file (HAR) instead of running that clumsy concatenation job -- that you don't seem to fully control?

Comment: @ Samson Scharfrichter - default field separator is TAB. I am trying to change that to something else (stream.map.output.field.separator), but with no avail yet.

Comment: @ Samson Scharfrichter - with HAR command, I can only point to a source DIR correct? Is there a way to select particular files with wild card (say *_0) as there may be other files there too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answerin this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133290/hadoop-streaming-remove-trailing-tab-from-reducer-output/18152110#18152110) -

Adding the below option seems to resolve it.

```
-D mapred.textoutputformat.separator=<delimiter-of-input-file>
```